# Show Details from any row in child component by click, by click on the same row close details doing on Angular 2+

Tags: angular, toggle

I need some help by toggle Values from a table row in a Child Component.

It should only be showen if i click on a row. This happens fine. But if i click in the next row it closes the Details, but it should only switch the value. If i click in the same row twice it should close the Details.

[Workaround here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vr9fqv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your toggleDetails function like this

```
toggleDetails(row) {
    console.log(row);
    if (this.rowData == row) {
      this.showDetails = !this.showDetails;
    } else {
      this.showDetails = true;
    }

    this.rowData = row;
  }
```

This will work!

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
toggleDetails(row) {
    console.log(row);
    this.showDetails = row.position !== this.rowData.position || !this.showDetails;
    this.rowData = row;
  }
```

Comment: Works but with small issue. "this.rowData.position" "Property position does not exists on type {}.

Comment: this.rowData : any = {} will fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

Please see the working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5ucfi). I have modified the `toggleDetails` method.